# Linux kernel 3.14: Cannot find LILO

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling

I'm trying to compile linux kernel `3.14` on ubuntu `14.04`. Before anyone points out, I know newer stable versions of the kernel are available but I have been asked to install `3.14` itself. So, I wrote a script which unpacks the source tar and starts building the kernel. But it stops mid way without generating any errors. I've tried to fiddle with the code and it still gives the same error every-time.

Snippet of the script:

```
# Prepare for compilation
make -j1 mrproper
# Set default configuration
make -j1 defconfig
# Compile the kernel image and modules
make -j1
# Install the modules
make -j1 modules_install
# Install the firmware
make -j1 firmware_install

# Install the kernel
cp -v arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage /boot/vm_linuz-3-14-systemd
# Install the map file
cp -v System.map /boot/system-map-3-14-systemd
# Backup kernel configuration file
cp -v .config /boot/config-backup-3-14
```

Last few lines of the log:

```
 LD [M]  net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_nat.ko
 LD [M]  net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_nat_ipv4.ko
 LD [M]  net/netfilter/nf_nat.ko
 LD [M]  net/netfilter/nf_nat_ftp.ko
 LD [M]  net/netfilter/nf_nat_irc.ko
 LD [M]  net/netfilter/nf_nat_sip.ko
 LD [M]  net/netfilter/xt_LOG.ko
 LD [M]  net/netfilter/xt_mark.ko
 LD [M]  net/netfilter/xt_nat.ko
 HOSTCC  arch/x86/boot/tools/build
 CPUSTR  arch/x86/boot/cpustr.h
 CC      arch/x86/boot/cpu.o
 MKPIGGY arch/x86/boot/compressed/piggy.S
 AS      arch/x86/boot/compressed/piggy.o
 LD      arch/x86/boot/compressed/vmlinux
 ZOFFSET arch/x86/boot/zoffset.h
 OBJCOPY arch/x86/boot/vmlinux.bin
 AS      arch/x86/boot/header.o
 LD      arch/x86/boot/setup.elf
 OBJCOPY arch/x86/boot/setup.bin
 BUILD   arch/x86/boot/bzImage
 Setup is 15232 bytes (padded to 15360 bytes).
 System is 5433 kB
 CRC 62b609cb
 Kernel: arch/x86/boot/bzImage is ready  (#1)

 Building modules, stage 2.
   MODPOST 11 modules
   CC      drivers/thermal/x86_pkg_temp_thermal.mod.o
   LD [M]  drivers/thermal/x86_pkg_temp_thermal.ko
   CC      net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_MASQUERADE.mod.o
   LD [M]  net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_MASQUERADE.ko
   CC      net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_nat.mod.o
   LD [M]  net/ipv4/netfilter/iptable_nat.ko
   CC      net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_nat_ipv4.mod.o
   LD [M]  net/ipv4/netfilter/nf_nat_ipv4.ko
   CC      net/netfilter/nf_nat.mod.o
   LD [M]  net/netfilter/nf_nat.ko
   CC      net/netfilter/nf_nat_ftp.mod.o
   LD [M]  net/netfilter/nf_nat_ftp.ko
   CC      net/netfilter/nf_nat_irc.mod.o
   LD [M]  net/netfilter/nf_nat_irc.ko
   CC      net/netfilter/nf_nat_sip.mod.o
   LD [M]  net/netfilter/nf_nat_sip.ko
   CC      net/netfilter/xt_LOG.mod.o
   LD [M]  net/netfilter/xt_LOG.ko
   CC      net/netfilter/xt_mark.mod.o
   LD [M]  net/netfilter/xt_mark.ko
   CC      net/netfilter/xt_nat.mod.o
   LD [M]  net/netfilter/xt_nat.ko
 sh /finalize-system/linux-kernel/linux-3.14/arch/x86/boot/install.sh      3.14.21 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
    System.map "/boot"
 Cannot find LILO.
```

It is showing an error `Cannot find LILO`. But I have installed `Grub 2` on my system. Then why is it asking for `LILO`?

Comment: why not make install too? Have you left /etc/lilo.conf behind?

Comment: I already have `Grub 2` on my system. Is there a way that `make` command skips checking for lilo and instead accepts grub that is already there on the system.

Comment: Have you or not the file `/etc/lilo.conf` present on your system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the `ARCH=x86_64` flag to all the `make` commands the Linux kernel was successfully compiled.